Modified graph Laplacian, D + A
Consider an undirected, connected graph with positive edge weights $G$ with adjacency matrix $A$ and (diagonal) degree matrix $D$, and graph Laplacian given by $L = D - A$. $L$ is singular and is non-invertible.
If we instead consider the matrix $B = D + A$ (i.e. the terms on the diagonal are the sum of the other terms in the corresponding row/column, and $B_{ij} = |L_{ij}|$), are there any properties we can deduce about $B$ and $B^{-1}$ (compared to $L$, or otherwise)? In particular,

Is it possible to directly compute $B^{-1}$?
Is $B$ positive definite?


This is called the sign less Laplacian and there's extensive literature on it available.

The sign-less Laplacian $B$ is positive semi-definite.
For the path graph with 2 vertices, the sign-less Laplacian is \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix} has the spectrum in $\{2,0\}$ and can't be inverted.
